# python - how to update pointer throughout functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have these two functions to find cycles in a graph (which is a dictionary):

```
def cycle_exists(G):
    color = { u : "white" for u in G}
    found_cycle = [False]

    for u in G:
        if color[u] == "white":
            dfs_visit(G, u, color, found_cycle)
        if found_cycle[0]:
            break
    if not found_cycle[0]:
        return None
    return found_cycle[1]

def dfs_visit(G, u, color, found_cycle):
    if found_cycle[0]:
        return
    color[u] = "gray"
    for v in G[u]:
        if color[v] == "gray":
            found_cycle = [True, v]
            return
        if color [v] == "white":
            dfs_visit(G, v, color, found_cycle)
    color[u] = "black"
```

When a cycle is found in `dfs_visit`, `found_cycle` gets assigned `[True, v]`, however when Python returns to `cycle_exists` function, `found_cycle` is still `False`. Why isn't it updating?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new list to `found_cycle`, which means no changes will be reflected in the calling function. So assuming you mean to update the original list you can:

```
found_cycle[0] = True
found_cycle[1] = v
```

Or more simply with a slice assignment:

```
found_cycle[:] = [True, v]
```

Or just return the value from `dfs_visit()`.

Answer (score 0):

The two `found_cycle`s are local to each function and cannot be shared. You should return its value and re-assign it:

```
def cycle_exists(G):
   ...
       found_cycle = dfs_visit(G, u, color, found_cycle)
```

and

```
def dfs_visit(G, u, color, found_cycle):
    ...
        return found_cycle
        ...
            return found_cycle
```

Comment: `found_cycle` is passed in so can be updated - lists are not immutable, however `return`ing a value is a much better approach.